# Iterating over a growing dictionary

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary, foreach, invalidoperationexception

I am working with C# and I have a dictionary called `intervalRecordsPerObject` of type `Dictionary<string, List<TimeInterval>>`. I need to iterate through the dictionary. The problem is: everytime I iterate through the dictionary, more `KeyValuePairs` may get added to it. As the dictionary grows, I need to keep iterating over the new entries too.

Firstly, I did this: A simple `foreach` loop that gave me an `InvalidOperationException` saying

> `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`

I know I cannot iterate over the Dictionary this way if it keeps changing as C# converts it with `ToList()` before `foreach` loop.

I know I can copy the keys to a temporary array, iterate over the dictionary using simple `for` loop and `Count` and whenever a new entry is added to the dictionary, add the corresponding key to the array too. Now, the problem is a simple array cannot grow dynamically and I don't know beforehand what the required size could be.

To move ahead, I thought I'd do this:

```
List<string> keyList = new List<string>(intervalRecordsPerObject.Count);
intervalRecordsPerObject.Keys.CopyTo(keyList.ToArray(), 0);
```

I cannot do this either. `keyList` is currently empty and therefore `keyList.toArray()` returns an array of length 0 which gives me an `ArgumentException` saying

> `Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the
>   collection. Check array index and length.`

I am stuck! Any idea what more can I try? Thanks for any help.

### Addition 1:

The dictionary stores the time intervals for which a particular object is present. Key is the ID of the object. New entries may get added in every iteration (worst case) or may not get added even once. Whether or not entries are added is decided by a few conditions (whether the object overlaps with some other intervals, etc.). This triggers a change in the ID and the corresponding interval list which is then added as a new entry to the dictionary.

Comment: Can you give some more context on what is the purpose of iterating over the dictionary, i.e. what are you trying to do? And how often do new elements get added?

Comment: If you have two threads accessing the same shared Dictionary object, you may have other potential problems waiting for you. You may benefit from using ConcurrentDictionary http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx

Comment: Even after your addition, I don't see why you need to iterate over the entire dictionary after a new entry is added. Why not just handle the fact that a new entry has been added, possibly to some running statistics you're storing somewhere? Once again, need more context.

Comment: Because the new added entry can trigger more new entries. This is done on the basis of comparison with some other intervals. Once, the list gets exhausted, no more entries can be added. What I need is the complete list of entries that are present in the dictionary at the end. I hope it clears some dust!

Comment: So then wait until all entries are added and iterate over the list? Seriously, it's hard to provide useful answers because your question description is assuming a solution, instead of explaining the actual thing you're trying to accomplish, and your comments aren't adding enough context. Try reducing the problem to its most essential form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
List<string> keys = dict.Keys.ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
{
    var key = keys[i];

    List<TimeInterval> value;

    if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out value))
    {
        continue;
    }

    dict.Add("NewKey", yourValue);
    keys.Add("NewKey");
}
```

The trick here is that you enumerate the `List<T>` by *index*! In this way, even if you add new elements, the `for (...)` will "catch" them.

Other possible solution, by using a temporary `Dictionary<,>`:

```
// The main dictionary
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<TimeInterval>>();

// The temporary dictionary where new keys are added
var next = new Dictionary<string, List<TimeInterval>>();

// current will contain dict or the various instances of next
// (multiple new Dictionary<string, List<TimeInterval>>(); can 
// be created)
var current = dict;

while (true)
{
    foreach (var kv in current)
    {
        // if necessary
        List<TimeInterval> value = null;

        // We add items only to next, that will be processed
        // in the next while (true) cycle
        next.Add("NewKey", value);
    }

    if (next.Count == 0)
    {
        // Nothing was added in this cycle, we have finished
        break;
    }

    foreach (var kv in next)
    {
        dict.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
    }

    current = next;
    next = new Dictionary<string, List<TimeInterval>>();
}
```

Comment: @DavidN Modified... Now it will skip the non-present keys.

Comment: A key is never removed from the dictionary.
Also, I don't get a suggestion for `ToList()` method on Visual Studio while typing `intervalRecordsPerObject.Keys.`. I don't know why. That could easily solve my problem.

Comment: @sleekFish Add `using System.Linq;` to your cs.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `Keys` by positions rather than by content and use a normal `For loop` (allowing additions/removals without any restriction).

```
for (int i = 0; i < dict.Keys.Count; i++)
{
    string curKey = dict.Keys.ElementAt(i);
    TimeInterval curVal = dict.Values.ElementAt(i);
    //TimeInterval curVal = dict[curKey];

   //Can add or remove entries
}
```